# Node fetch JSON data is not iterable

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I am getting an error of `TypeError: data.events is not iterable` when using `fetch` to retrieve `JSON` data from an `API`.

I am pretty sure it is in my handling of the `JSON` in `for (const event of data.events)` from the below code but I am pulling short on finding a fix.

```
const data = fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + bearerToken,
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
});

for (const event of data.events) {
    let fileNode;
    try {
        fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
            url: logo.original.url,
            cache,
            store,
            createNode,
            createNodeId
         });
    } catch (error) {
        console.warn('error creating node', error);
    }
}
```

The `JSON` when requested in Postman is `returned` as

```
{
    "pagination": {
        ...
    },
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "Example One",
            "logo": {
                "original": {
                    "url": "exampleURL"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Example Two",
            "logo": {
                "original": {
                   "url": "exampleURL"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "location": {
        ...
    }
```

}

The goal is to `createRemoteFileNode` for each event from `logo.original.url`

Comment: fetch is an async (promised) method so you should use `fetch(url...).then(data => data.json()).then(data => for (const event of data.events) {`

Comment: fetch returns a promise, there's no data.events at the time of you're trying to access it

Comment: Quite a few questions like this one have been closed pointing to How to return the response from an asynchronous call - the question does ask for how to handle the reponse in a loop which is IMHO specific enought to give a specific answer especially with a few lines of example code. The generic answers (to a different related question) are IMHO far too complex in their structure  - the full complexity of the implementation is exposed and explained to the reader while the question here is about the  interface and the result not the inner workings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fetch() returns a promise so `data.events` does not exist until the fetch promised is resolved. Edit your code this way:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + bearerToken,
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
}).then(function(data){

  for (const event of data.events) {
      let fileNode;
      try {
          fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
              url: logo.original.url,
              cache,
              store,
              createNode,
              createNodeId
           });
      } catch (error) {
          console.warn('error creating node', error);
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: `await` must be inside an `async` function

Comment: Thank you Scott. I had moved from `axios` get to `fetch` and that appears to have been my mistake in not returning the promise.